TCP traffic blocked until mapped drive authenticated
I have (and fixed) an issue where TCP traffic was being blocked between two applications. During diagnosis, I had noticed that a mapped drive between the two machines was not authenticating. Deleting and remapping the drive with working credentials resolved the mapped drive issue...and also the TCP connection between the applications.
This strongly implies that there was a hidden authentication step between the two applications via TCP. However, another oddity was that I was able to successfully ping one machine from the other which means a valid TCP packet was sent and acknowledged - not authenticated.
I'm wondering if anyone can explain the behaviour? I'm clearly missing a step in my understanding of the connection/auth process.
I'm not sure if it's relevant but the server was WXP and the client OS is W10. The W10 machine had the SMB 1 protocol installed.
